# Surface Distance

Tags: distance

I'm really stuck and i can't find any thing helpful in the net about surface distance, what is it and how can i calculate it.

Comment: Given the available data, I would say it is a distance from a surface. There really isn't anything else one can conclude from your question. Calculate surface distance from what? What kind of surface? In what form is the input data given? What coordinate system? ... anything.

Comment: @Rook: The other alternative is the distance *along* a surface.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - Fair point! In any case he needs to provide more data.

Comment: check geodesic distance op wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing the problem here involves distance between two points on the surface of the earth. If the two points are close together you can treat the earth as flat and use the Pythagorean Theorem:

http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm

If they're further apart you need to consider the fact that the earth is spherical. The distance between two points in this case along the surface of the earth is the "great circle" distance:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Neither of these methods include the influence of local topology (hills), obstacles (like rivers), or vehicles restricted to a network of routes (roads, railways), all of which complicate the calculations.

Make sure you understand the difference between Nautical Miles and Statute Miles if you try to implement these algorithms, or your solution will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

#### Surface Distance based metrics (with spacing as default)

- [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance)
- Hausdorff distance 95% percentile
- Mean (Average) surface distance
- Median surface distance
- Std surface distance

**Note**: These metrics are **symmetric**, which means the distance from A to B is the same as the distance from B to A.

For each contour voxel of the segmented volume (A), the Euclidean distance from the closest contour voxel of the reference volume (B) is computed and stored as `list1`. This computation is also performed for the contour voxels of the reference volume (B), stored as `list2`. `list1` and `list2` are merged to get `list3`.

- `Hausdorff distance` is the maximum value of `list3`.
- `Hausdorff distance 95% percentile` is the 95% percentile of `list3`.
- `Mean (Average) surface distance` is the mean value of `list3`.
- `Median surface distance` is the median value of `list3`.
- `Std surface distance` is the standard deviation of `list3`.

**References:**

1. Heimann T, Ginneken B, Styner MA, et al. Comparison and Evaluation of Methods for Liver Segmentation From CT Datasets. IEEE Transactions on Medical Imaging. 2009;28(8):1251–1265.
2. Yeghiazaryan, Varduhi, and Irina D. Voiculescu. "Family of boundary overlap metrics for the evaluation of medical image segmentation." Journal of Medical Imaging 5.1 (2018): 015006.
3. Ruskó, László, György Bekes, and Márta Fidrich. "Automatic segmentation of the liver from multi-and single-phase contrast-enhanced CT images." Medical Image Analysis 13.6 (2009): 871-882.

[`seg-metrics`](https://github.com/Jingnan-Jia/segmentation_metrics) is a simple package to compute different metrics for **Medical** image segmentation(images with suffix `.mhd`, `.mha`, `.nii`, `.nii.gz` or `.nrrd`), and write them to csv file.